# Efecto hover: Mostrar imagen cuando paso el mouse sobre una etiqueta <a>

Tags: html, css, hover

estoy intentando crear un efecto Hover al pasar el mouse por una etiqueta  que contiene un texto muestre una imagen a la izquierda del texto y cuando salga de ese mismo texto la imagen vuelva a desaparecer. Dejo imagenes de ejemplos y el codigo que estuve intentado hacer.

El problema es que cuando paso el cursor aparece la imagen pero no desaparece cuando dejo de pasar el cursor por el texto...[![

```js
const text = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

Array.from(text).forEach((elemento) => {
  
  elemento.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    let cases = elemento.getAttribute("data-cases");
    const img = document.getElementById("img");
    
    switch(cases) {
      case "quietevents": var stringImg = `<img src="https://www.google.com/search?q=imagen&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=AJOqlzUgAQmBXD_KBxLGA2fk2seqEnU__A:1675053965247&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC3s-kvu78AhUPQ7gEHSUmDKAQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw#imgrc=oe0lpOI26S6OUM" width="100" height="100">`;
    }
    
    img.innerHTML = stringImg;
    
  });

});
```

```css
.list-cases a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "maison-neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 25px;
    /* or 125% */
    color: black;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}


#img img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 462.06px;
    height: 294px;
    left: -510px;
    top: 4px;
}


.list-cases a:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 17px;
    padding-right: 369px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-cases">
            <div id="img"></div>
            <a class="text" data-cases="quietevents" href="#">Quietevents</a>
        </div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8qxj.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8qxj.png)

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `display` para mostrar u ocultar la imagen y en el contenedor `display: inline-block` y aplicar el `hover` al contenedor.

Ejemplo (Dejé únicamente los estilos necesarios, agrega el color y demás estilos que necesites):

```css
 .list-cases {
   display: inline-block;
 }

.list-cases img {
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
.list-cases:hover img { 
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="list-cases">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="image"/>
  <a class="text" data-cases="quietevents" href="#">Quietevents</a>
</div>
```